# Cartopy:'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'-Geograph plotting of population literacy

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, data-visualization, cartopy

Here is the data set I have and after cleaning and excluding others I make a set as such-
[image]

I intend to make geographical plot using `cartopy`

steps I am following are:

- From the shapefile get the names of states
- Create a map
- Drawing states from shapefile
- A function to add features
- Plot the graph

Here is the code in  `cartopy python3`

Modules Imported-

```
import pandas as pd
from itertools import groupby
from __future__ import division
import operator
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib.cbook import CallbackRegistry
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.feature import ShapelyFeature
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import math
```

```
states_group = states_group.copy()

#Calculate litracy rate using vector formula which is faster and more.
states_group['literacy_rate'] = 100*(states_group['P_LIT'] + states_group['F_LIT'])/states_group['TOT_P']

# use to_records to get list of tuples
literacy = states_group[['Name','literacy_rate']].to_records(index=False)
list(literacy)

states= shpreader.Reader('/home/user/Downloads/India_SHP/INDIA.shp')
states= states.records()   
states=next(states)
#print(type(states.attributes))   
#print(sorted(states.attributes.keys()))
```

Creating a graph-

```
crs=ccrs.PlateCarree()
extent=[68.60,97.23,35.40,6.33]

def draw_india(ax):
    ax.set_extent(extent)
    ax.coastlines()
    
    
fig,ax=plt.subplots(1,1,figsize=(6,8),subplot_kw=dict(projection=crs))    
draw_india(ax)
```

[image]
This the output I get as I intend to.

```
def choropleth(ax, literacy, cmap_name):
    # We need to normalize the values before we can
    # use the colormap.
    #values = [state.attributes[attr] for state in states ]
    norm = Normalize(
        vmin=min(literacy), vmax=max(literacy))
    cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap(cmap_name)
    for state in states:
        v = state.attributes[literacy['literacy_rate']]    
 #ERROR-TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
        sp = ShapelyFeature([state.geometry], crs,
                            edgecolor='k',
                            facecolor=cmap(norm(v)))
        ax.add_feature(sp)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(
    1, 1, figsize=(10, 16),
    subplot_kw=dict(projection=crs))
draw_india(ax)                     #Draw india's graph
choropleth(ax, literacy, 'Reds')    #passing literacy(list) 
ax.set_title('Literacy')
```

Note:

Link to - [Notebook](https://github.com/Irene-123/Cartopy-data-sets-and-notebooks/blob/main/Untitled.ipynb)

Link to - [Reference code for Africa](https://github.com/Irene-123/Cartopy-data-sets-and-notebooks/blob/main/Africa.ipynb)

Link to - [shape file and data set](https://github.com/Irene-123/Cartopy-data-sets-and-notebooks)

**EDIT:**

The problem is in data structure `literacy`
In the function choropleth , instead of passing the data frame , only the column with intended values is being passed now .So the new function looks like -

```
def choropleth(ax, literacy, cmap_name):
    # We need to normalize the values before we can
    # use the colormap.
    #values = [state.attributes[attr] for state in states ]
    norm = Normalize(
    vmin=min(literacy), vmax=max(literacy))
    cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap(cmap_name)
    for state in states:
#Error Here on this line 
        v = state.attributes[literacy]
        sp = ShapelyFeature([state.geometry], crs,
                            edgecolor='k',
                            facecolor=cmap(norm(v)))
        ax.add_feature(sp)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(10, 16),
    subplot_kw=dict(projection=crs))
draw_india(ax)
choropleth(ax, literacy['literacy_rate'], 'Reds')
ax.set_title('Literacy')
```

But it still gives an error regarding the type of data structure being passed.

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Should this line `ax1.set_title('Literacy')` not be `ax.set_title('Literacy')`?

Comment: Yes I have corrected that . But that wasn't the main issue @RuthgerRighart

Comment: Can you please help me out with the error ? @RuthgerRighart             ```TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'numpy.ndarray'```

Comment: Could you check the indentation after fig,ax?

Comment: Error still persist. It was not an indentation

Comment: Could you add for states group data to your question so I can run your code?

Comment: https://github.com/Irene-123/Cartopy-data-sets-and-notebooks/blob/main/state_dist_sc.xls         @RuthgerRighart

Comment: I hope the data set was useful @RuthgerRighart

Comment: Please add a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help users answering this question. For Python you need to include your module imports. This will help you get high quality answers

Comment: I have added the modules. Please do check it. @marcos

Comment: OP don't edit the question to change the issue. This defeats the purpose of SO. It's not a forum. Please check out the [good question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ask a new question.

Comment: Okay I'll make sure . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the data structure `literacy`. You need to pass a list or array to matplotlib.colors.Normalize. You can solve this by extracting the numerical literacy values like so:

```
    norm = Normalize(
    vmin=min(literacy['literacy_rate']), vmax=max(literacy['literacy_rate']))
```

This way, you will pass a numpy array `literacy['literacy_rate']`:

```
array([ 79.9703704 ,  74.98720319,  96.10132857, ..., 101.62102523,
   100.12902706, 105.12942069])
```

Rather than a structure with strings and numbers `literacy`:

```
rec.array([('India',  79.9703704 ), ('India',  74.98720319),
       ('India',  96.10132857), ..., ('Karaikal', 101.62102523),
       ('Karaikal', 100.12902706), ('Karaikal', 105.12942069)],
      dtype=[('Name', 'O'), ('literacy_rate', '<f8')])
```

Comment: I am getting an error on this line ```v = state.attributes[literacy['literacy_rate']]```    ```TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'```    in the function ```choropleth```

Comment: Please check the edit in the question and help me

Comment: If you have a new issue you need to ask a new question.

Comment: Also your edit ignores the fix in this answer